# Locating Exception from Release Stack Trace

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.android, async-await

I have a Xamarin Android application that is deployed to testers which is crashing intermittently. I log the stack trace when the application has an unhandled  exception however I'm having difficulty locating the source of the crash from the trace. I found this article about getting file names / line numbers in release build stack traces and implemented it in my code (https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_6/xamarin.android_6.1/#Release_Stack_Traces). Note I did have to  change debugging information option to "Full" to get the build process to generate the msym directory.

I tested the functionality by adding a button to my app that raises an unhandled exception. As expected I was able to use the mono-symbolicate utility to determine the origin of the exception from the reported stack trace.

I noticed that the contents of the msym folder is named randomly so after rebuilding the app I deployed the new build and saved off the msym directory. The following is a stack trace I  received from a crash report.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

 at MyApp.Droid.Dashboard.DashboardActivity+<OnResume>d__18.MoveNext () [0x0003b] in <e3858b3570dd4244985ab7c8da45615a>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n 
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <151302d8db184dfd9dfbf4e0ac550df9>:0 \n 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <151302d8db184dfd9dfbf4e0ac550df9>:0 \n 
 at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <c8c020c6a36f47959fcbe54313f43792>:0 \n 
 at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <c8c020c6a36f47959fcbe54313f43792>:0 \n 
 at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <c8c020c6a36f47959fcbe54313f43792>:0 \n 
 at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.452a73e4-d2f9-4ade-a6c1-b8346138dd0d(intptr,intptr)","reportType":"UHELogEntry","timestamp_ticks":636894071182040326}
```

However when  I run the mono-symbolicate utility on the above trace the utility complains with the following warning.

```
    Warning: MVID directory does not exist: .\e3858b3570dd4244985ab7c8da45615a
```

Its easy to see that the exception is coming from the OnResume method of the DashboardActivity (see below). But there are several possible sources of the exception but none of them seem probable so I'd like to have a better idea of where the exception is coming from before I go on several wild goose chases.

```cs
protected override async void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    var provider = KernelBuilder.KERNEL.Get<ServiceProvider>();
    await provider.initializationTask;

    _service = provider.getService();
    Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("OnResume, post service assignment", "Service: " + (_service?.ToString() ?? "null")));

    var wrapper = new ExerciseServiceWrapper(_service, null);
    _connectionView.Setup(wrapper, _service.userSetupHardware);

    _service?.stopRecordingSession();
    LibITagAndroid.ContinuousITagClickSrc.instance.stop();
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Why is the mono-symbolicate tool not able to translate the stack traces to a file / line number?
2. Is it possible to use the information encoded in the method name at the top of the stack trace (MyApp.Droid.Dashboard.DashboardActivity+d__18.MoveNext) to narrow down where the exception is coming from? It seems like the d__18 suffix may indicate if the exception happened before or after the call to await provider.initializationTask but I haven't found anything to help me understand this suffix.

An Additional Observation:

I noticed that if I set debugging information to "Full" and disable "Optimize Code" I get a file path / line numbers reported in the stack trace of my testing exceptions but not of the exception occurring in the OnResume function. This makes me think this is happening somewhere "special" maybe provider.initializationTask is null?

Thanks!

John

Comment: Firstly, do you follow this link when you use this tool :https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/mono-symbolicate. You get `  Warning: MVID directory does not exist: .\e3858b3570dd4244985ab7c8da45615a`, is that a warring Completely? This warring should provide a path about dir.

Comment: Thank you for replying, and sorry for the delay responding. I read the link but I think Xamarin does all of this already for me since there is a mSYM folder in archive directory. Am I missing something? I don't think I understand your comment about the warning. I ran the mono-symbolicate tool in the mSYM directory so the path is "./" if I run it outside the mSYM directory I get an error like this "Warning: MVID directory does not exist: ./mSYM\47795ed9a0b341aca6806beb315db6fa".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of waiting for Xamarin/App Center/other services to solve this, and looked into solving it myself. In short, what I did:

1. Handle unhandled exceptions
2. In the handler, create a custom stack trace with IL offsets and method tokens
3. Send this as a handled exception to App Center (you can send it anywhere)
4. Once there is a stack trace, use official APIs from .net to symbolicate the stack trace to get line numbers (and even column numbers)

You can see exactly how I did it here: https://github.com/rhult/crash-sharpener

Of course, you can automate a lot of this by downloading crashes from App Center or wherever you post them and do the symbolicating automatically. I hope this helps, it made my life a lot easier. It works for both iOS and Android.